# how to send muliple emails in drupal in same time

Tags: 7, forms, emails

in my site when user submit a dination i want to send email to donor,charity and delivery service at same time(three different emails) in code and i want to kown how can i achieve that,below is the my mail seding function,i already tried call email function with 3 times with different keys for `$key` but that time emails are sending with out body content

```
 function zgRequestsdonor2_mail ($key, &$message, $params) {
  switch ($key) {
  case 'aftersubmit_donor':
    // Set headers etc

    $message['subject'] = t('email to donor');
    //$message['body'][] = t('Hello @username,', array('@username' => $params['username']));
    $message['body'][] = 'tyrtyrtyrtyty';
    break;
  }
}
```

calling it at

```
function zgRequestsdonor2_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {
  drupal_mail('zgRequestsdonor2','aftersubmit_donor',$donoremail, $language, $params = array(), $from = NULL, $send = TRUE);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to send same mail to donor, charity and delivery service, then you can use CC feature of the mail.

```
$message['headers']['CC'] = "myemail@me.com";
```

Comment: no i want to send three diffrent emails to them..,i tried call the mail function three times but then emails are send with out body content...